# Jquery if target element is visible on screen quasion

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dom, scroll, onload

i am using wordpress, and we have there dynamic sidebar. in the sidebar we have many widgets.
what am i trying to do is to show the divis (widgets) that visible on the screen (onload - after the page is load). the others widgets will be hidden(opacity 0 or something like that) but when i will scroll i want that widget(that was not visible on screen) will appear in fade effect.

i using this code that hide all my sidebar block is on opacity 0 on load.

i need help to show always all widgets that is visible on screen and then make the fade effect on scroll to others.

thanks for help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
tiles = $("#sidebar1 div").fadeTo(0, 0);
});
$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
    });
});
```

the funcasion for scrolling is working. the problem is that when the page is full load my sidebar class that hold all widgets is on opacity 0 (like display:none). what i need is when the page load it will give opacity 1 to all widgets that visible on screen (for example 2 of 10 widgets). then when user will scroll it will show others widgets each by other with fade effect. thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

on window scroll you can check this:

```
 tiles.each(function(){ 
      if($(this).css("opacity") == 0){
         //your hidden div
      }else{
         //your visible div
      }
 });
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello @maverickosama92 it did not work because all the sidebar from the beginning is on opacity 0 so this function is always will return false. thanks for help.

Comment: Hello @maverickosama92, thanks for help. this may help, but how can i know witch wigets is "on the screen area"?

Comment: @need-help:: i think position() will help you find the div that is on area or not.. or have a look on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling?rq=1